# What collab. software do I need?

Tags: php, mysql, sharepoint

I'm in a bit of a situation right now. I need software that does the business side of Sharepoint. The software will be used in a company intranet.

Ideally, I'd go with SharePoint, and although what I'm technially looking for is a PHP Sharepoint alternative, PHP is not tasked up to deal with the same tasks as SharePoint.

What I don't want is something that lives in a Java instance, that just eats up away lots of RAM either.

### Product Specifications

- Document Management System
- Collaboration Systems
- Some sort of  notices system
- Office-like system, where documents can be uploaded and downloaded
- A Wiki System, please!

### Coding Specifications

- PHP or other, nice language
- **Use MySQL**

A ticketing and calendar system is not essential, but would be nice.

I'm sure software like this must live somewhere, but has anyone seen it?

If worst comes to the worst, I might end up coding parts of it myself. But I'd rather not do that.

At this moment in time, price isn't a great factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tiki Wiki](http://info.tikiwiki.org/tiki-index.php) is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Does Tiki Wiki have some sort of notices system, I couldn't find one, but I'll try it out when I'm at home :)

Answer (score 1):

I work on Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware and I'll share a few links to cover your requirements.

> "Document Management System" & "Office-like system, where documents can be uploaded and downloaded"

- http://doc.tiki.org/File+Gallery
- http://doc.tiki.org/Docs (web-based ODFs)
- http://doc.tiki.org/Spreadsheet (web-based)
- http://doc.tiki.org/Slideshow (web-based)

> "A Wiki System, please!"

- http://doc.tiki.org/Wiki

> "Some sort of notices system"

- http://doc.tiki.org/Watch

> "Collaboration Systems"

Well, the whole thing is a collaborating system, built by a collaborative community :-)

- Software made the wiki way: http://tiki.org/Model

> "Coding Specifications"

- PHP scripting language
- MySQL database
- Smarty template engine
- jQuery JavaScript library
- Zend Framework

> "A ticketing and calendar system is not essential, but would be nice."

- http://doc.tiki.org/Trackers (way more than just ticketing)
- http://doc.tiki.org/Calendar

> I'm sure software like this must live somewhere, but has anyone seen it?

- http://tiki.org/FOSS+Web+Application+with+the+most+built-in+features

> If worst comes to the worst, I might end up coding parts of it myself. But I'd rather not do that.

Just join the project and improve what you think needs it:
http://dev.tiki.org/How+to+get+commit+access

> At this moment in time, price isn't a great factor.

Well, if you have money burning your pockets :-)

- http://tiki.org/Donation